# Algolia Search + Magento 2 + Bug

Tags: search, magento2, algolia

I am geeting below error when run reindex commnad from Algolia search.

`Algolia Search Products index PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Http\Psr7\Uri::withScheme(string $scheme): Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface must be compatible with Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface::withScheme($scheme) in /var/www/html/vendor/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php/src/Http/Psr7/Uri.php on line 439`

Currently I am using Version

```
algolia/algoliasearch-magento-2": "3.8.1"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This issue can happen if you are using a package which that packages uses older versions of `psr/http-message` (under 1.1).
Consider checking your `package.lock` to see what version of `psr/http-message` is used.
Also, you can run `composer require psr/http-message:1.1` and if an error comes up you can see what package is using an older version of this package.